# How do I export my Exchange/Outlook contacts to iCloud with photos intact?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, contacts, icloud

I know how to export contacts from Exchange/Outlook via the .csv route (e.g. export as CSV, import into Gmail, export as vCard, then import into iCloud).  But that method loses all the photos that are attached my contacts.

Is there a way to move my contacts to iCloud with photos intact?

Comment: Did you originally manually add those pictures to the Outlook contacts yourself? A CSV file is text-only, so to start you'd have to export in a different format. PST is *probably* the only one that actually holds the pictures on export.

Answer (score 1):

There are utilities to help with this.  For example [CopyTrans Contacts](http://www.copytrans.net/):

> CopyTrans Contacts makes managing your iPhone contacts breathtakingly easy. 
>    Organise, edit and delete contacts quickly. Back up and export contacts onto your PC.

Here's a [link to their instructions](http://www.copytrans.net/support/how-to-transfer-outlook-contacts-to-icloud/) on using their software to transfer Outlook contacts to iCloud, it seems to show pictures are moved as well.

Blurb:

> Importing contacts from Outlook on PC to an iCloud account was until recently a complicated matter which involved syncing an iOS device to iTunes. Not any more: you can now use CopyTrans Contacts and after a few clicks transfer Outlook contacts to your iCloud account.

Note: I have never used that particular software. :)

Comment: That is a good option, but it is a paid one.  Don't want to spend money on a one time thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that works on 10.10:

Configure your exchange account in Systems Preferences/Internet Accounts.

Open the contacts app. In the left hand bar, select Exchange/Contacts, then drag and drop all the contacts you want to the iCloud section.

Answer (score 0):

In outlook i clicked on contacts.   i selected the folder i wanted to copy i put the cursor on one of the contacts and clicked on it.  I then went to edit (options at the top of screen) and selected "select all".  In edit menu again I selected "copy to folder".  I then selected the folder where i wanted to copy the contacts, icloud contacts.  And voila.
I then logged in to my icloud contacts and on the bottom left hand corner clicked on settings "refresh contacts"